# Drawing HSV Gradient failed

Tags: c, rgb, color-picker, hsv

For the drawing process i have these 3 functions:

`void setpen(R, G, B)` - Sets the current brush's color

`void putpixel(X, Y)` - puts pixel at X Y using the brush

I am trying to draw the HSV gradient:

[image]

using this pair of code:

```
int S, H;

for(S = 0; S<255; S++)
{
    for(H = 0; H<255; H++)
    {
        setpen(S, H, H);
        putpixel(S, H);
    }
}
```

But the gradient drawn from this code is:

[image]

Not like it looks bad, but its not the result i really want. Also as i see there is something correct at the top-right side.. but at the bottom-left it goes in cyan.
Please, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: can you try `setpen(S, 255-(H/S), 255-(H/S))`?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yeah and thats the result: http://vegasoft.site90.com/result.png Looks exactly as Android's image sign effect when you reach the end of the album

Comment: Nope. Thats the result from your update: http://vegasoft.site90.com/new.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have shown, you want a gradient with fixed hue (red), saturation going up and value going right.

When you convert a color from HSV to RGB with `H = 0` (red hue) :
- `R = V`
- `G = B = V * (1 - S)`

In your case, for some `x` and `y` in `[0; 255]` you want the following :
- `V = x`, hence `R = x` ;
- `S = 255-y`, hence `G = B = x * y`.

So you can change your call to `setpen` like this :
`setpen(S, (H*S) / 255, (H*S) / 255);`

Comment: I didn't get how am i supposed to apply this to make it work.

Comment: Just replace the line in your code ? What is wrong ?

Comment: It woerked! Thank you. Really.

Comment: damn. i knew it should have been simple. i just couldn't figure out the color math in my head. good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the variables S and H. I assume you intend for this to stand for "saturation" and "hue", but what you actually want is "saturation" and "lightness" (or "value"), as the hue is always red. Working left-to-right (the inner loop) our lightness will go from zero to 255.

You'll need a function to convert from HSL to RGB. I found an implementation of such a function from [this website](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) and reproduced it below.

```
void HSLtoRGB( int *r, int *g, int *b, int h, int s, int l )
{
    int i;
    double f, p, q, t;
    if( s == 0 ) {
        // achromatic (grey)
        *r = *g = *b = l;
        return;
    }
    h /= 60.0;          // sector 0 to 5
    i = floor( h );
    f = h - i;          // factorial part of h
    p = l * ( 255 - s );
    q = l * ( 255 - s * f );
    t = l * ( 255 - s * ( 1 - f ) );
    switch( i ) {
        case 0:
            *r = (int) l;
            *g = (int) t;
            *b = (int) p;
            break;
        case 1:
            *r = (int) q;
            *g = (int) l;
            *b = (int) p;
            break;
        case 2:
            *r = (int) p;
            *g = (int) l;
            *b = (int) t;
            break;
        case 3:
            *r = (int) p;
            *g = (int) q;
            *b = (int) l;
            break;
        case 4:
            *r = (int) t;
            *g = (int) p;
            *b = (int) l;
            break;
        default:        // case 5:
            *r = (int) l;
            *g = (int) p;
            *b = (int) q;
            break;
    }
}
```

To tie it into your code, simply do as follows:

```
int H, S, L;
H = 0; // ranges from 0 to 359 (degrees), 0 == red
for(S = 0; S<255; S++)
{
    for(L = 0; L<255; L++)
    {
        int r, g, b;
        HSLtoRGB(&r, &g, &b, H, S, L);
        setpen(r, g, b);
        putpixel(L, 255-S);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but. The compiler im using can't convert from `int*` to `float*` so i just changed it to `float *r, *g, *r;` Also it gives buffer overflow from these pointers. Allocated 256 bytes for each of them, but the result is wrong. It looks like a simple red gradient that goes darker.

Comment: try initializing them as `float r, g, b;` and calling `HSLtoRGB(&r, &g, &b, H, S, L);`. remember to make H, S, and L floats as well.

Comment: It can't convert from `double` to `float*`

Comment: @Edenia i don't see where `double`s are involved, but the other solution was better anyway. unless you need it to support an arbitrary hue.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow `double` are args from `setpen();`.
And this is a mandatory association.

Comment: @Edenia oh, then is there a problem with just replacing all the instances of `float` with `double` in your code? i've updated the example.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow On the following line: `HSLtoRGB(r, g, b, H, S, L);`
It says that it cannot convert from `double` to `double*` If i put reference before `r, g, b` the result is a entirely white drawing.

Comment: sorry, i had accidentally put ampersands in the wrong place. should be `HSLtoRGB(&r, &g, &b, H, S, L)` and `setpen(r, g, b)`. example is updated. this is what i get for trying to compile it in my brain.

Comment: Doing it on that way.. the result is a simple red gradient. :(
Darkness-Red

Comment: it looks like the `HSLtoRGB` function works on a scale of 0.0 to 1.0 rather than 0 to 255. try passing S and L divided by 255, and multiply r g and b by 255 after the conversion. code is updated.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow OH! Now it appears working. But it is.. a bit.. rotated: http://vegasoft.site90.com/like.png

Comment: @Edenia try switching the arguments on the `putpixel` function?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yeah but the result is still flipped upsite-down. Now at leasts it is correct at the x. However.. i like it more on that way. Thank you :) Now i gotta find a way to make the drawing faster. It really draws from the CPU.